# Catalina (10.15.5) Spotlight calculator CPU spike?

Tags: catalina, spotlight, performance

I noticed that I would have insane CPU spikes (400%+) whenever I type in a math equation (even something simple like 1+2) into spotlight. The task that spikes is called mds_stores. Does anyone know if this is just an issue with my system/is there some sort of software fix coming?

Attached = picture of the spike

[image: High CPU spike]

Comment: on Mojave I can see a simple calculation does make mds_stores spike for one refresh cycle, but in my case it's about "half a core" not "four cores". If I lift Activity Monitor's update frequency to  very fast (1s) then I see 'one core' for about 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue too, on two Macs. As a workaround I've had to kill mds_stores and launch an app, the App Store or something to have the CPU return to idle.

Here is the bug in action:
https://youtu.be/Ymc5ElAdUIQ

I've reported to Apple FWIW.